# PostgreSQL export to a new row in an existing csv

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I'm using Postico at the moment to query the database. I need to run a daily query to extract information created the previous day. I have created a query that works, although I'm having trouble exporting the table.

I know I can manually export to a new CSV everyday, but I would like to know if there's a way (within Postico or any other client) to export to an existing CSV (and create a new row/sheet).

Thanks!

Comment: Copy to a new CSV and append it to the existing one by other means

Comment: Have you looked at the [file foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html)? I'm pretty sure it will be able to solve your problem, though it's a bit heavyweight.

Comment: No I haven't yet. I will check it out today. Thanks!